# Check for updation of records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wish to know is it possible to check is there any updation in records in a table for specific period of time

Id  Name    Ligin

0   Abc1    Yes

1   Abc 2   No

I mean i wish to check if there any updation of these two rows in 3 months without setting any `Datetime`

Comment: you are not setting any column for time but wants to check according to time. How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No In MYSQL you cannot, get the timestamp of the row created or updated, you need to define your methods(adding a column), to do so

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean, without setting any `DateTime` *manually*?

There is a way to create an auto-update `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
  ...,
  last_update DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Then just select records by giving a constraint for `last_update` in `WHERE` clause.

See more details here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html